# Get file name from the string using php

Tags: php

I want to get file name (with extension .png or .jpg or .gif) from the string given below :

```
    {src:"brand.png", id:"brand"},
    {src:"centpourcent.png", id:"centpourcent"},
    {src:"corsa.png", id:"corsa"},
    {src:"cta.png", id:"cta"},
    {src:"neons.png", id:"neons"}
```

From the above string i want to get output like :

```
[ brand.png, centpourcent.png, corsa.png, cta.png, neons.png ] // Or may be as string output
```

I tried below code but it didnt work for me:

```
substr($images, strpos($images, "src:") + 5);
```

Im getting output as

```
        brand.png", id:"brand"},
        {src:"centpourcent.png", id:"centpourcent"},
        {src:"corsa.png", id:"corsa"},
        {src:"cta.png", id:"cta"},
        {src:"neons.png", id:"neons"}
```

Comment: Where does the string come from? It kind of looks like broken json.

Comment: It will depend on how the src is generated. Is this information coming from a MySQL table?

Comment: Its coming from js file

Comment: What do you mean by _"Its coming from js file"_? Do you mean that you read read and parse a js file using PHP, or do you mean the js is making a request to PHP, passing the string as a parameter, using ajax? The best solution would most likely be to make sure that string is properly formatted so you can just do `json_decode()` to get it as a proper PHP structure.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$string = '{src:"brand.png", id:"brand"},
    {src:"centpourcent.png", id:"centpourcent"},
    {src:"corsa.png", id:"corsa"},
    {src:"cta.png", id:"cta"},
    {src:"neons.png", id:"neons"}';

// Here I replace the src with "src" and id with "id"
$string = str_replace(['src', 'id'], ['"src"', '"id"'], $string);
// Then I wrap all the string in brackets to convert the string to valid JSON string.
$json = '[' . $string . ']';
// Finally I decode the JSON string into a PHP array.
$data = json_decode($json);
// Here I am going to save the images names.
$images = [];

// Here I iterate over the json body entries and I push into the $images array
// the image name
foreach($data as $entry) {
    array_push($images, $entry->src);
}

// And here I just print it out, to make sure the output is the following:
print_r($images);

// OUTPUT:
// Array
// (
//     [0] => brand.png
//     [1] => centpourcent.png
//     [2] => corsa.png
//     [3] => cta.png
//     [4] => neons.png
// )
```

Comment: @VinoCoder if you got the right answer, please consider marking this answer as the right one by clicking the checkmark right below the voting buttons :) Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can preg_match_all() use to get all file names.

```
$str = '{src:"brand.png", id:"brand"},
    {src:"centpourcent.png", id:"centpourcent"},
    {src:"corsa.png", id:"corsa"},
    {src:"cta.png", id:"cta"},
    {src:"neons.png", id:"neons"}';

$r = preg_match_all('~(?:src:")([^"]+)(?:")~',$str,$match);

var_dump($match[1])
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "brand.png"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "centpourcent.png"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "corsa.png"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "cta.png"
  [4]=>
  string(9) "neons.png"
}
```

Added:

If a valid JSON string is to be generated from the specified string, this can also be done with a regular expression.
The algorithm also works without changes with keys other than 'src' and 'id'.

```
$jsonStr = '['.preg_replace('~\w+(?=:)~','"$0"', $str).']';
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use Regex:
`(?<=")[^\\\/\:\*\?\"\<\>\|]+\.(?:png|jpg|gif)(?=")`